# Перестает отображаться икона на FAB

Tags: android

У меня в приложении используется одно `activity` на котором меняются фрагменты так же есть `bottom navigation` и `fab` которые скрываются или показываются в зависимости от текущего фрагмента.
У `fab` в некоторых случаях нужно изменять иконку, смена делается следующим образом:
`fab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_done))`
Не могу понять причину по которой fab так себя ведет, в консоли никаких ошибок нет.
В гифке показан пример того как ведет себя fab.

#### UPDATE

Решил сделать скрытие через анимацию масштаба и оси Y, пока никаких проблем не вижу.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Так себя ведет" это как?

Comment: @Эникейщик на гифке же видно что иконка перестает отображаться.

Comment: Если правильно помню, то там был какой-то косяк, если FAB скрыта, что-то игнорировалось. Скорее всего подобное и у вас. Советую не играть с FAB, а повесить на каждый фрагмент свою.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja поэксперементировав я понял что все ломается после скрытия кнопки. Я бы рад в каждый фрагмент свою кнопку добавить, но тогда она не будет прилипать к BottomNavigation и следовать за ним при скрытии навигации.